# How to read from shell console event more efficiently ?

Tags: c#, shell, console

A simple console code which read the console called ShellStream,

```
private ShellStream Shell;

public TelnetConnection(string Hostname, int Port, string MySSHHost, string MySSHRootUser, string MySSHRootUserPassword)
       {   
               SshConnection(MySSHHost, MySSHRootUser, MySSHRootUserPassword);            
               shell.DataReceived += new EventHandler<ShellDataEventArgs>(shell_DataReceived);   /// Created a event

       }
```

So, a event is created below

```
private void shell_DataReceived( object sender, ShellDataEventArgs e)
       {
           ScbyteReceived = e.Data;
           string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Data, 0, e.Data.Count());
           ConsoleRead = result; <---------------------here
           Console.WriteLine(result);
       }
```

Now I want to read from the event real time, so i create a string variable "ConsoleRead" and passed the "result" to it

then in another function i started reading from Console read like below

```
public string ReadWithTimeOut(int Tout)
   {
       long  mycount = 0;
       if (!sshClient.IsConnected) return null;
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       do
       {
           //ParseTelnet(sb);
           sb.Append(ConsoleRead);    /// <-----------------here
           System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeOutMs);
           mycount += TimeOutMs;
       } while (mycount < (long) Tout);
       return sb.ToString();
   }
```

I know this is not the correct way. can you guys suggest me a better way to read from shell console in real time and pass it to ReadWithTimeOut() method . note i call  ReadWithTimeOut  method only when needed with a time.

Comment: Well to be fair your readwithtimeout doesnt really do the reading, it just checks if there have been reads.. offhand this doesnt look like a way Id do it, but sometimes needs must and Ive never used shellstream so I cant argue theres a better way but it does sound like there should

Comment: what is the other way u have used to read from console ?

Comment: I use the chillkat product, howeevrr, it does sound like you need to just buffer the data up and after a timer, process it

Comment: @BugFinder HI, i have posted the answer which i found is suitable. pls accept if u also think the same. thanks

Comment: I cant accept it, its not my question

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is the solution I found and all you need do is use Shell.read() instead of a string "ConsoleRead" . no need to crating a shell event ( in my case ).
hope this helps some one in the future.

```
 do
       {  
           //sb.Append(ConsoleRead);    /// <-----------------here
           sb.Append(shell.Read());    // use this instead to read directly, more efficient than previous method
           System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeOutMs);
           mycount += TimeOutMs;
       } while (mycount < (long) Tout);
         return sb.ToString();
```